# Non-vanishing terms of Maclaurin series for $\log(3-\cos x^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have to find the first two non-vanishing terms in the Maclaurin series of
$$g(x) = \log(3 − \cos(x^2))$$

and that prove $x=0$ is a stationary point.

What is a quick way of working out the Maclaurin series?

I know that $\log(1+x)= x- x^2/2! + x^3/3!- x^4/4!+\ldots $.

How can you relate $\log(x+1)$ to $\log(3-\cos(x^2))$?

Answer (score 0):

Since in a neighbourhood of zero we have:
$$1-\cos(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\ldots $$
it happens that:
$$1-\cos(x^2) = \frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{x^8}{4!}+\ldots $$
and:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\log(3-\cos(x^2)) &=& \log(2+(1-\cos(x^2))) = \log 2 + \log\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x^2}{2}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\log 2+\frac{x^4}{4}+\ldots}.\end{eqnarray*} $$
Obviously $x=0$ is a stationary point since $g(x)$ is an even smooth function in a neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: I don't really understand

Comment: @Tk706: I cannot give you a hand if you are not more specific. I am just computing the Taylor series of a composition of two analytic functions.